# MAC address randomizer - MAC Address does not change?

Tags: bash, macos, mac-address

I've tried to create a small and basic bash script to change my MAC address on MacOS, upon reboot. The script trows no errors, however nor does it change my mac address.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo echo "Welcome"

preAddress="$(ifconfig en0|grep ether)"

numZero=2
numOne=$(( ( RANDOM % 9 )  + 0 ))
numTwo="$(openssl rand -hex 1)"
numThree="$(openssl rand -hex 1)"
numFour="$(openssl rand -hex 1)"
numFive="$(openssl rand -hex 1)"
numSix="$(openssl rand -hex 1)"

newAddress="$numZero$numOne:$numTwo:$numThree:$numFour:$numFive:$numSix"

sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport --disassociate
sudo ifconfig en0 ether $newAddress
networksetup -detectnewhardware
sudo ifconfig en0 up

echo "MAC Address changed to: $newAddress from$preAddress"
```

I've re-used some code, originally posted here: [Post 1 user: seren/user137369](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151986/change-mac-address-in-os-x-yosemite), [Post 2 User: Luke Exton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277918/shell-script-to-generate-random-hex-numbers), [Post 3 User: OrangeTux/py4on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988824/generating-random-number-between-1-and-10-in-bash-shell-script).

In short, the script creates a set of variables which all contains a random number. These variables are formatted as a MAC Address in another variable. I then change (or at least try to) the current MAC address to the random one.

But when I run this, I see no change under Network>Advanced in system settings or if I run "ifconfig" in the terminal?

I've also tried to just copy in the following to the terminal, but no dice..:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 down
sudo ifconfig en0 ether 27:ab:29:b9:be:ef
sudo ifconfig en0 up
```

I simply cannot figure out why this does not work.. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of macOS is this? What does `ifconfig en0` say after you run this by hand?

Comment: @RobNapier - So it works for you? 

if I use "ifconfig en0" it simply has the permanent MAC Address (original)..

Comment: Yeah; works without trouble. macOS 10.14.3, just running the 3 lines by hand, and then checking w/ `ifconfig eth0`.

Comment: I'm on 10.14.1, which should be a deal breaker as far as I know. You say the three separate lines work, but does it work if you use the entire script then?