# How can I randomize a number with 32 hexadecimal digits?

Tags: bash, shell, random, random-seed

I am trying to randomize a number with 32 hexadecimal digits in bash with seed which depends on the date.
I thought about something like: `RANDOM=$(date +%N | cut -b4-9)` , but it's not give me 32 hexadecimal digits.

ideas?

Comment: Which `date` do you use, GNU or FreeBSD(macOS uses)?

Comment: @ConstantinHong I just run the above command in bash.

Comment: `date +%N | md5sum | cut -c1-32`, though its randomness is debatable.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin what is the purpose of `md5sum` in your command?

Comment: @Software_t md5sum is a 128-bit hash, thus 32 hexadecimal digits.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Are you tried it? i don't get it as 32 hexadecimal digits ..

Comment: `RANDOM` is an OS variable that generates a somewhat-random 16-bit number ... nowhere near enough to generate a 32-digit hex value

Comment: why the requirement to use a date (nanoseconds) as a seed? are you actually going to save the `date +%N` output for later use (eg, to reseed `RANDOM`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a random string of 32 hexadecimal digits through command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328759) or [Shell script to generate random hex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40277918)

Comment: @Software_t  Sure, I've tried it. You must certainly get a 32-xdigit number (tough its randomness is debatable).

Comment: Why are you specifically using date as seed? Is that *necessary*? It's seed only, so isn't it better to just assure you have sufficiently random data?

Comment: Attempting to override the built-in variable `RANDOM` is separately an error. You won't get back the value you assigned. Perhaps see also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 0):

I'm always generating with: openssl rand -base64 32

Comment: i asked random with date

Answer (score 0):

Feed `/dev/urandom` to `tr` and delete all but hex digits:

```
$ tr -dc '[:xdigit:]' < /dev/urandom | head -c32
90D75De9CaA0C38a15B8facf59CBBDdc
```

---

If you need all upper (or all lower):

```
$ tr -dc '0-9A-F' < /dev/urandom | head -c32
CBABC737B0F9C059531CA7672FCA52F6

$ tr -dc '0-9a-f' < /dev/urandom | head -c32
87fa3f2e4f98a8e8eecb8236e2736eba
```

Comment: but i aksed for random number according to seed that related to date

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate your need for the date.
If it's an assignment, say so.

Assuming it is -

```
$: src="0123456789ABCDEF" && RANDOM=$(( $(date +%s) % 32767 ))    &&
>  for c in {1..32}; do printf "%s" ${src:$((RANDOM%16)):1}; done &&
>  echo 
14E4552562D03BB6FCAC8602B0D38BE7
```